# Integrating CCAvenue with php

Tags: php, ccavenue

I am a total newbie to payment gateways.
I would like to integrate CCAvenue to my website using PHP.
I have downloaded their Intergration kit, Included my merchant id and working key, set the account to active and tried to do a dummy transaction on the index file they have provided in my localhost.

But,when I click on submit on the form it is taking me to CCAvenue Transaction error page without any error code and error description.

Please let me know where I am making the mistake and what else I need to do.

I would be great if anyone pointed to me to a tutorial other then the CCAvenue integration manual.

Codes:
    Checkout.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Checkout</title>
</head>
<body>

 <?php include('adler32.php')?>
 <?php include('Aes.php')?>
 <?php 

 error_reporting(0);
 $merchant_id=$_POST['Merchant_Id'];  // Merchant id(also User_Id) 
 $amount=$_POST['Amount'];            // your script should substitute the amount here                        in the quotes provided here
 $order_id=$_POST['Order_Id'];        //your script should substitute the order   description here in the quotes provided here
 $url=$_POST['Redirect_Url'];         //your redirect URL where your customer will be redirected after authorisation from CCAvenue
 $billing_cust_name=$_POST['billing_cust_name'];
 $billing_cust_address=$_POST['billing_cust_address'];
 $billing_cust_country=$_POST['billing_cust_country'];
 $billing_cust_state=$_POST['billing_cust_state'];
 $billing_city=$_POST['billing_city'];
 $billing_zip=$_POST['billing_zip'];
 $billing_cust_tel=$_POST['billing_cust_tel'];
 $billing_cust_email=$_POST['billing_cust_email'];
 $delivery_cust_name=$_POST['delivery_cust_name'];
 $delivery_cust_address=$_POST['delivery_cust_address'];
 $delivery_cust_country=$_POST['delivery_cust_country'];
 $delivery_cust_state=$_POST['delivery_cust_state'];
 $delivery_city=$_POST['delivery_city'];
 $delivery_zip=$_POST['delivery_zip'];
 $delivery_cust_tel=$_POST['delivery_cust_tel'];
 $delivery_cust_notes=$_POST['delivery_cust_notes'];


$working_key=/*MY working Key*/;    //Put in the 32 bit alphanumeric key in the quotes provided here.


 $checksum=getchecksum($merchant_id,$amount,$order_id,$url,$working_key); // Method to       generate checksum

  $merchant_data=    'Merchant_Id='.$merchant_id.'&Amount='.$amount.'&Order_Id='.$order_id.'&Redirect_Url='.$url  '&billing_cust_name='.$billing_cust_name.'&billing_cust_address='.$billing_cust_address.'&billing_cust_country='.$billing_cust_country.'&billing_cust_state='.$billing_cust_state.'&billing_cust_city='.$billing_city.'&billing_zip_code='.$billing_zip.'&billing_cust_tel='.$billing_cust_tel.'&billing_cust_email='.$billing_cust_email.'&delivery_cust_name='.$delivery_cust_name.'&delivery_cust_address='.$delivery_cust_address.'&delivery_cust_country='.$delivery_cust_country.'&delivery_cust_state='.$delivery_cust_state.'&delivery_cust_city='.$delivery_city.'&delivery_zip_code='.$delivery_zip.'&delivery_cust_tel='.$delivery_cust_tel.'&billing_cust_notes='.$delivery_cust_notes.'&Checksum='.$checksum  ;

$encrypted_data=encrypt($merchant_data,$working_key); // Method for encrypting the data.

?>

<form method="post" name="redirect"   action="http://www.ccavenue.com/shopzone/cc_details.jsp"> 
<?php
   echo "<input type=hidden name=encRequest value=$encrypted_data>";
   echo "<input type=hidden name=Merchant_Id value=$merchant_id>";

    ?>
 </form>
 <script type='text/javascript'>document.redirect.submit();</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And my Redirecturl.php

```
<?php include('Aes.php')?>
<?php include('adler32.php')?>
<?php


error_reporting(0);
$workingKey=/*My Working Key*/;     //Working Key should be provided here.
$encResponse=$_POST["encResponse"];         //This is the response sent by the CCAvenue Server


$rcvdString=decrypt($encResponse,$workingKey);      //AES Decryption used as per the specified working key.
$AuthDesc="";
$MerchantId="";
$OrderId="";
$Amount=0;
$Checksum=0;
$veriChecksum=false;

$decryptValues=explode('&', $rcvdString);
$dataSize=sizeof($decryptValues);
//******************************    Messages based on Checksum & AuthDesc   **********************************//
echo "<center>";


for($i = 0; $i < $dataSize; $i++) 
{
    $information=explode('=',$decryptValues[$i]);
    if($i==0)   $MerchantId=$information[1];    
    if($i==1)   $OrderId=$information[1];
    if($i==2)   $Amount=$information[1];    
    if($i==3)   $AuthDesc=$information[1];
    if($i==4)   $Checksum=$information[1];  
}

$rcvdString=$MerchantId.'|'.$OrderId.'|'.$Amount.'|'.$AuthDesc.'|'.$workingKey;
$veriChecksum=verifyChecksum(genchecksum($rcvdString), $Checksum);

if($veriChecksum==TRUE && $AuthDesc==="Y")
{
    echo "<br>Thank you for shopping with us. Your credit card has been charged and your transaction is successful. We will be shipping your order to you soon.";

    //Here you need to put in the routines for a successful 
    //transaction such as sending an email to customer,
    //setting database status, informing logistics etc etc
}
else if($veriChecksum==TRUE && $AuthDesc==="B")
{
    echo "<br>Thank you for shopping with us.We will keep you posted regarding the status of your order through e-mail";

    //Here you need to put in the routines/e-mail for a  "Batch Processing" order
    //This is only if payment for this transaction has been made by an American Express Card
    //since American Express authorisation status is available only after 5-6 hours by mail from ccavenue and at the "View Pending Orders"
}
else if($veriChecksum==TRUE && $AuthDesc==="N")
{
    echo "<br>Thank you for shopping with us.However,the transaction has been declined.";

    //Here you need to put in the routines for a failed
    //transaction such as sending an email to customer
    //setting database status etc etc
}
else
{
    echo "<br>Security Error. Illegal access detected";

    //Here you need to simply ignore this and dont need
    //to perform any operation in this condition
}


echo "<br><br>";


//************************************  DISPLAYING DATA RCVD ******************************************//

echo "<table cellspacing=4 cellpadding=4>";
for($i = 0; $i < $dataSize; $i++) 
{
    $information=explode('=',$decryptValues[$i]);
        echo '<tr><td>'.$information[0].'</td><td>'.$information[1].'</td></tr>';
}

echo "</table><br>";
echo "</center>";
?>
```

I have also included Adler.php and Aes.php which comes with the integration kit

Comment: show some code where have you integrated it.

Comment: have you solved this issue. Now I am facing the same.

Answer (score 5):

ccavenue payment gateway integration is very simple and easy, please copy below php code or php script for ccavenue payment gateway integration and set the variable value as per you account.

```
<?php 

function getchecksum($MerchantId,$Amount,$OrderId ,$URL,$WorkingKey) 
{ 
    $str ="$MerchantId|$OrderId|$Amount|$URL|$WorkingKey"; 
    $adler = 1;
    $adler = adler32($adler,$str); 
    return $adler; 
}   

function verifychecksum($MerchantId,$OrderId,$Amount,$AuthDesc,$CheckSum,$WorkingKey) 
{ 
    $str = "$MerchantId|$OrderId|$Amount|$AuthDesc|$WorkingKey"; 
    $adler = 1; 
    $adler = adler32($adler,$str);   
    if($adler == $CheckSum) 
        return "true" ; 
    else 
        return "false" ; 
}   


function adler32($adler , $str) 
{ 
    $BASE = 65521 ;   
    $s1 = $adler & 0xffff ; 
    $s2 = ($adler >> 16) & 0xffff; 
    for($i = 0 ; $i < strlen($str) ; $i++) 
    { 
        $s1 = ($s1 + Ord($str[$i])) % $BASE ; 
        $s2 = ($s2 + $s1) % $BASE ; 
    } 
    return leftshift($s2 , 16) + $s1; 
}  



function leftshift($str , $num) 
{   
    $str = DecBin($str);   
    for( $i = 0 ; $i < (64 - strlen($str)) ; $i++) 
        $str = "0".$str ;   
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $num ; $i++) 
        $str = $str."0"; $str = substr($str , 1 ) ;  
    return cdec($str) ; 
}   


function cdec($num) 
{   
    for ($n = 0 ; $n < strlen($num) ; $n++) 
    { 
        $temp = $num[$n] ; 
        $dec = $dec + $temp*pow(2 , strlen($num) - $n - 1); 
    }   
    return $dec; 
} 


$Merchant_Id = "User ID" ;//This id(also User Id) available at "Generate Working Key" of "Settings & Options" 
$Amount = 'Total Amount';//your script should substitute the amount in the quotes provided here 
$Order_Id = "Order ID";//your script should substitute the order description in the quotes provided here 
$Redirect_Url = "Your Return URL" ;//your redirect URL where your customer will be redirected after authorisation from CCAvenue   
$WorkingKey = "Your Working Key" ;//put in the 32 bit alphanumeric key in the quotes provided here.Please note that get this key ,login to your CCAvenue merchant account and visit the "Generate Working Key" section at the "Settings & Options" page. 
$Checksum = getCheckSum($Merchant_Id,$Amount,$Order_Id ,$Redirect_Url,$WorkingKey);   
$billing_cust_name=$customer_name; 
$billing_cust_address=$customer_address; 
$billing_cust_state=$customer_statename; 
$billing_cust_country=$customer_country;
$billing_cust_tel=$customer_contact_no;
$billing_cust_email=$customer_email; 
$delivery_cust_name=$customer_name; 
$delivery_cust_address=$customer_address; 
$delivery_cust_state = $customer_statename; 
$delivery_cust_country = $customer_country; 
$delivery_cust_tel=$customer_contact_no; 
$delivery_cust_notes=$customer_message;  
$billing_city = $customer_city; 
$billing_zip = $customer_zipcode; 
$delivery_city = $customer_city; 
$delivery_zip = $customer_zipcode; 
?> 



<form name="paymentform" method="post" action="https://www.ccavenue.com/shopzone/cc_details.jsp">
    <input type="hidden" name="Merchant_Id" value="<?php echo $Merchant_Id; ?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="Amount" value="<?php echo $Amount; ?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="Order_Id" value="<?php echo $Order_Id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="Redirect_Url" value="<?php echo $Redirect_Url; ?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="Checksum" value="<?php echo $Checksum; ?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_cust_name" value="<?php echo $billing_cust_name; ?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_cust_address" value="<?php echo $billing_cust_address; ?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_cust_country" value="<?php echo $billing_cust_country; ?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_cust_state" value="<?php echo $billing_cust_state; ?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_zip" value="<?php echo $billing_zip; ?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_cust_tel" value="<?php echo $billing_cust_tel; ?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_cust_email" value="<?php echo $billing_cust_email; ?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="delivery_cust_name" value="<?php echo $delivery_cust_name; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="delivery_cust_address" value="<?php echo $delivery_cust_address; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="delivery_cust_country" value="<?php echo $delivery_cust_country; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="delivery_cust_state" value="<?php echo $delivery_cust_state; ?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="delivery_cust_tel" value="<?php echo $delivery_cust_tel; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="delivery_cust_notes" value="<?php echo $delivery_cust_notes; ?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="Merchant_Param" value="<?php echo $Merchant_Param; ?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_cust_city" value="<?php echo $billing_city; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_zip_code" value="<?php echo $billing_zip; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="delivery_cust_city" value="<?php echo $delivery_city; ?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="delivery_zip_code" value="<?php echo $delivery_zip; ?>"> 
    <INPUT TYPE="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Can I Test in localhost? if so do I have to do any settings?

Comment: Is your registered ccavenue account is in INR currency or US Dollar currency?

ccavenue avenue does not allow to test US Dollar currency from other domain, it will only work for live site which is mentioned in ccavenue. Only Indian currency could be test from localhost and other currencies are excluded for localhost.

Comment: user2936213, I will take care of it next time.

Comment: @appWOZ Yes it is Indian Currency. Please check my code and let me know what I have done wrong

Comment: have you solved this issue. Now I am facing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to Integrate Payment Gateway :

1. At first create a merchant account on 
   https://dashboard.ccavenue.com/web/registration.do?command=Preview.
2. After successful registration CCavenue team will verify your provided phone no. and email Id.
3. After account activation your website will be verified and the team will provided your the merchant Id and working key which will be needed while integrating the payment gateway.
4. Login to your account on https://dashboard.ccavenue.com/jsp/merchant/merchantLogin.jsp
5. Go to dashboard and click on setting tab then select API KEYS.
6. Copy all three keys Merchant ID, Access Code and  Working Key.

   **Now follow the following code steps to integrate Ccavenue :**

   Create a file containing the form e.g. **index.php** and paste below code:

   Follow below link for step by step execution :

https://www.lelocode.com/posts/integrate-ccavenue-payment-gateway-in-php-with-simple-step---lelocode