# php ccavenue integeration : 'Error Code: 10001 Invalid Request - Encrypted request invalid/not present.'

Tags: php, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I used the code mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21301200/7599905)   .First I get the error

> 'Notice: Undefined variable: dec in on line 62'

. ie. inside the function cdec().

When I click submit, I get the 1001 Error. I have registered the url to 192.168.0.100:8000. The working and merchant id works when I tried it with the test kit given by ccavenue. But their code has mcrypt which is depreciated now. I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
 <?php

        function getCheckSum($MerchantId,$Amount,$OrderId ,$URL,$WorkingKey)
        {
            $str ="$MerchantId|$OrderId|$Amount|$URL|$WorkingKey";
            $adler = 1;
            $adler = adler32($adler,$str);
            return $adler;
        }

        function verifyCheckSum($MerchantId,$OrderId,$Amount,$AuthDesc,$CheckSum,$WorkingKey)
        {
            $str = "$MerchantId|$OrderId|$Amount|$AuthDesc|$WorkingKey";
            $adler = 1;
            $adler = adler32($adler,$str);

            if($adler == $CheckSum)
                return "true" ;
            else
                return "false" ;
        }

        function adler32($adler , $str)
        {
            $BASE =  65521 ;

            $s1 = $adler & 0xffff ;
            $s2 = ($adler >> 16) & 0xffff;
            for($i = 0 ; $i < strlen($str) ; $i++)
            {
                $s1 = ($s1 + Ord($str[$i])) % $BASE ;
                $s2 = ($s2 + $s1) % $BASE ;
                //echo "s1 : $s1 <BR> s2 : $s2 <BR>";

            }
            return leftshift($s2 , 16) + $s1;
        }

        function leftshift($str , $num)
        {

            $str = DecBin($str);

            for( $i = 0 ; $i < (64 - strlen($str)) ; $i++)
                $str = "0".$str ;

            for($i = 0 ; $i < $num ; $i++)
            {
                $str = $str."0";
                $str = substr($str , 1 ) ;
                //echo "str : $str <BR>";
            }
            return cdec($str) ;
        }

        function cdec($num)
        {

            for ($n = 0 ; $n < strlen($num) ; $n++)
            {
                $temp = $num[$n] ;
                $dec =  $dec + $temp*pow(2 , strlen($num) - $n - 1);
            }

            return $dec;
        }



    $Merchant_Id = /*merchant_id*/ ;
    $Amount = '1000';
    $Order_Id = "ORDER102030sd40";
    $Redirect_Url = //redirecturl;   
    $WorkingKey = /*working key*/ ;
    $customer_name = 'Sai';
    $Checksum = getCheckSum($Merchant_Id,$Amount,$Order_Id ,$Redirect_Url,$WorkingKey);  

    $delivery_cust_address= 'Chennai'; 
    $billing_cust_name= 'Sai';
    $billing_cust_country= 'India';
    $billing_cust_state= 'Tamilnadu';
    $billing_cust_city= 'Chennai';
    $billing_zip= '600056';
    $billing_cust_tel= '9003321521';
    $billing_cust_email= 'sai@gmail';
    $delivery_cust_name= 'Sai';
    $delivery_cust_country= 'India';
    $delivery_cust_state= 'Tamilnadu';
    $delivery_cust_city= 'Chennai';
    $delivery_zip= '600056';
    $delivery_cust_tel= '9003321521';
    $delivery_cust_email= 'sai@gmail'; 
    ?> 



<form name="paymentform" method="post" action="https://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction">
    <input type="text" name="merchant_id" value="<?php echo $Merchant_Id; ?>"> 
    <input type="text" name="amount" value="<?php echo $Amount; ?>"> 
    <input type="text" name="order_id" value="<?php echo $Order_Id; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="redirect_url" value="<?php echo $Redirect_Url; ?>"> 
    <input type="text" name="checksum" value="<?php echo $Checksum; ?>"> 
    <input type="text" name="billing_cust_name" value="<?php echo $billing_cust_name; ?>"> 
    <input type="text" name="billing_cust_address" value="<?php echo $delivery_cust_address; ?>"> 
    <input type="text" name="billing_cust_country" value="<?php echo $billing_cust_country; ?>"> 
    <input type="text" name="billing_cust_state" value="<?php echo $billing_cust_state; ?>"> 
    <input type="text" name="billing_zip" value="<?php echo $billing_zip; ?>"> 
    <input type="text" name="billing_cust_tel" value="<?php echo $billing_cust_tel; ?>"> 
    <input type="text" name="billing_cust_email" value="<?php echo $billing_cust_email; ?>"> 
    <input type="text" name="delivery_cust_name" value="<?php echo $delivery_cust_name; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="delivery_cust_address" value="<?php echo $delivery_cust_address; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="delivery_cust_country" value="<?php echo $delivery_cust_country; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="delivery_cust_state" value="<?php echo $delivery_cust_state; ?>"> 
    <input type="text" name="delivery_cust_tel" value="<?php echo $delivery_cust_tel; ?>">     

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `$dec =  $dec +.....` If dec has not previously been defined how can you `add` it to something ? Initialise it outside the loop `$dec=0;`

Comment: Yes. I have also tried $dec = null. Your solution fixes that bug. But I still get the 10001 error :/

Comment: Can you explain _But their code has mcrypt which is depreciated now_

Comment: In the example code given by ccavenue, mcrypt is used, which is not compatible with newer version of php. I tested it with an older installation of xampp, and  I didn't get any errors.

Comment: Then you may be limited to using an older version of PHP until they upgrade their API